# Bulk copy from SQL Server to PostgreSQL

Tags: sql-server, postgresql

I need to copy a large SAP table (28 columns with mostly nvarchar, 100 mio records) from a SQL Server into a PostgreSQL database as fast as possible every day (delta update is not possible) using Python.

Before copying, I have created an empty table with the same structure (equivalent data types) like the source table in the PostgreSQL database.

Right now I am using the following implementation based on the read_sql_query method from pandas for reading and the copy_from
method for writing and it takes ~1 min for copying 1 mio records.

> Does anyone know a faster implementation or have ideas for optimization?. I already switched the driver to ODBC and dropped all constraints in the target table like primary keys.

PS: the ETL tool Pentaho Dataintegration is two times faster and is a benchmark for me.

SQL create statement for creating the empty target table in the PostgreSQL database:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS q_nlei (
  mandt varchar(3),
  einri varchar(4),
  falnr int,
  leist varchar(10),
  lnrls varchar(10),
  lfdbew varchar(5),
  anfoe varchar(8),
  anman varchar(1),
  erboe varchar(8),
  erman varchar(1),
  haust varchar(2),
  preis decimal(13,2),
  abrkz varchar(1),
  imeng varchar(4),
  ibgdt date,
  iendt date,
  ibzt time,
  iezt time,
  tarif varchar(2),
  tarls varchar(10),
  tarsp varchar(2),
  erdat date,
  updat date,
  storn varchar(1),
  remrk varchar(40),
  anpoe varchar(8),
  refky varchar(20),
  thergroup smallint);
```

Python script for copying data:

```
import pandas as pd
import io
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

src_engine = create_engine(f"mssql+pyodbc://{usr}:{pw}@{host}:1433/{db}?driver=ODBC+Driver+17+for+SQL+Server", fast_executemany=True)
snk_engine = create_engine(f"postgresql+psycopg2://{usr}:{pw}@{host}/{db}")

sql_query = "SELECT * FROM Q_NLEI"

for chunk in pd.read_sql_query(sql_query, src_engine, chunksize = 500000):
  chunk.columns = map(str.lower, chunk.columns)

  # Prepare data
  output = io.StringIO()
  chunk.to_csv(output, sep='\t', header=False, encoding="utf8", index=False)
  output.seek(0)
  # Insert data
  connection = snk_engine.raw_connection()
  cursor = connection.cursor()
  cursor.copy_from(output, snk_tbl, sep='\t', null='')
  connection.commit()
  cursor.close()
```

Comment: Is a linked server an option for you, so that you can perform this without the intermediate steps of converting to and from CSV format? If you've been able to benchmark the process with Pentaho, why not continue to use that?

Comment: Hi, I guess to establish a linked server I need admin permissions, right? but unfortunately I do not have those. Pentaho is really nice if you just want to copy the table once with a GUI and the target table already exists, but I want a flexible application that is able to create automatically new tables based on the source table and I need to copy the data every day triggered by a bash script. Additionally, Pentaho consumes lots of memory.

Comment: Have you looked at SSIS then? It comes with SQL Server and with the right driver, can connect to Postgres as well.